# How can I make common search code available to all of my model classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, rails-activerecord, decorator

I am trying to refactor a search method into a new class because I find myself using it in nearly every model in my app:

```
  def self.text_search(query)
    if query.present?
      where("username @@ :q or email @@ :q", q: query).order(
        updated_at: :desc)
    else
      order(updated_at: :desc)
    end
  end
```

The params `username` and `email` change depending on the model, but I have 3 models where I use the same functionality with two different params. My idea is to use a decorator, like this:

```
class SearchModel < SimpleDelegator

    def text_search(param1, param2, options={})
        query = options[:query]
        if query.present?
            __getobj__.where("#{param1} @@ :q or #{param2} @@ :q", q:query).order(updated_at: :desc)
        else
            order(updated_at: :desc)
        end
    end
end
```

I am calling `SearchModel` like this:

```
SearchModel.new(User.all).text_search('username', 'email', query: "admin")

SearchModel.new(User.all).text_search('username', 'email')
```

and it gives me what I want, but I am not sure if I am using a decorator in the correct way. Would this type of refactor be more appropriate in some other part of Ruby's standard library, or is this what decorators are for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a decorator is a more elaborate approach than most people would use, and leads to a complicated calling syntax. I would do it like this:

```
module TextSearchSupport
  def text_search(*args)
    search_term = if args.last.responds_to(:[]) then args.pop[:query] end
    query =
      if search_term
        where(args.map { |arg| "#{arg} @@ :q" }.join(' or '), q: query)
      else
        scoped
      end
    query.order(updated_at: :desc)
  end
end
```

and `extend TextSearchSupport` in each model that needs it. Then you can just call text_search('foo', 'bar', query: 'query') on the model.

A couple of asides:

- it is nicer to handle any number of fields rather than hardcoding, so I did that
- I think you want `scoped` rather than `all` to avoid running the query right away, so I used that, but you say your version was working so not sure what was going on there.

Comment: that's really elegant - I was wondering how to address more/less fields with my approach.